# How to pass a constructor parameter to another constructor with Spring

Tags: java, spring, constructor

I have 2 classes:

```
@Component("baseWebElement")
@Scope("prototype")
@Lazy(true)
public class BaseWebElement implements IBaseWebElement{

@Autowired
private IContextBrowserDriver browserDriver;

private String locator;

@Autowired
public BaseWebElement(String locator)   {
    this.setLocator(locator);
}
...
```

And:

```
@Component("webLink")
@Scope("prototype")
@Lazy(true)
public class WebLink implements IUILink, ApplicationContextAware {

private ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

@Autowired
private IBaseWebElement baseWebElement;

public WebLink(String locator) {

}
...
```

As you can see I want to use the BaseWebElement in the WebLink class.
Both of them have a constructor which has the same parameter. (locator)

I want to pass the WebLink constructor parameter to the BaseWebLink constructor.

How can I do this with Java Spring annotations correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using instance instead of inheritance.